# Importing specific objects from "export default" results in "undefined"

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm learning Webpack and therefore testing out some different methods I've observed.

I've created the following JS file, which was a method for exporting I observed in a NPM package.

```
// test.js
const Foo = { myVar: "Foo" }
const Bar = { myVar: "Bar"}

export default {
    Foo,
    Bar
}
```

And inside my `app.js` I write the following:

```
// app.js
import { Foo } from './test'

console.log(Foo);
```

I was expecting that I would get the `Foo` object from my exported object in `test.js` but I just get an `undefined` in the console. Also, Webpack says:

```
"export 'Foo' was not found in './test'
```

So, removing the the curly brackets from the import:

```
// app.js
import Temp from './test'

console.log(Temp);
```

This produces an object, containing the `Foo` and `Bar` objects.

What is wrong and right here?

Comment: Take off the `default` from your `export` statement. You should only use the `default` keyword when you're exporting one thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the default keyword, that's for specifying what your default export is, not for all your exports. You're currently saying that your entire object of exports is the default.

```
export {
    Foo,
    Bar
}
```

The default is for saying if something wasn't specified, this should be the default, e.g:

```
export {
    Foo as default, // import WhateverIWantToCallIt from './test'
    Foo, // import { Foo } from './test'
    Bar // import { Bar } from './test'
}

// Or you can export things separately:

export function Bar() {...}
export function Foo() {...}
export default Foo; // Declare what the default is
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing destructering with named imports

```
//this is not destructing but named imports
import { Foo } from './test'


// this is default export. 
export default { Foo, Bar }
```

in order to use named imports you have to use named exports .

as other comments has already explained you have to use

`export` without `default`

```
// test.js
const Foo = { myVar: "Foo" }
const Bar = { myVar: "Bar"}

export default {
    Foo,
    Bar
}


// app.js
import { Foo } from './test'

console.log(Foo); // works as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually export an object with two parameters:

```
module.exports = {Foo, Bar}
```

If you want to use `import {Foo} from './file'` syntax you should export your constants separately

```
export const Foo = { myVar: "Foo" }
export const Bar = { myVar: "Bar"}
```

Comment: When would you use `module.exports` over just `export`?

Comment: @Dan no, I use export/export default. I wrote `module.exports` here just for clarity